# VBA Select range with two variables

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range, selection

I am trying to select range. I have no problem selecting it with variable, lets say x and y are variables. I have no problem writing code to select range from e.g. `A1:By`. But How do I select a range from `Ax:By` ? Is there simple one line solution to this?

Thanks in advance for help

My code for A1:By which works

```
Sheets("Sim").Range("A1:B" & y).Select
```

My made code from Ax:By which does not work

```
Sheets("Sim").Range("A" & x ":B" & y).Select
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out an ampersand....

```
Sheets("Sim").Range("A" & x & ":B" & y).Select
```

Comment: beat me be seconds.

Comment: FWIW; @JiříJezdinský one should avoid using `.Select` and just do the action wanted. ie `Sheets("Sim").Range("A" & x & ":B" & y).Copy`

Comment: Thanks for the solution (I just totally forgot about another &). And also thanks for the select notice.