# Autofill a range that consists of two variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following VBA-code in an attempt to make sure that all the cells in a particular cell range consist of the same formula. This cell range changes continuously. Therefore, both cells (begin- and end cell) are variable and not static.

```
Range("C" & LastRowOld).Select
With Range("C" & LastRowOld)
    .Formula = "myFormula"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("C" & LastRowOld & ":C" & LastRowNew)
```

Earlier in my VBA-macro I declared the variables *LastRowOld* and *LastRowNew.*

When debugging I get an error on the following line

```
.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C" & LastRowOld & ":C" & LastRowNew)
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? I tried to incorporate the answers of the following question: [VBA Select range with two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449578/vba-select-range-with-two-variables)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What error is showing?

Comment: why are you using AutoFill at all? Putting the formula into the range already puts the formula into the range.

Comment: Try `.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C" & LastRowOld, "C" & LastRowNew)`

Comment: @BruceWayn I get the following error message _Autofill method of Range classes failed_.

Comment: @virtuadvid Your proposal doesn't work as it shows the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Ive tried your code and it works fine for me, have you checked for an issue with your variables? 
Add

```
debug.print LastRowOld 
debug.print LastRowNew
```

before the 'with' to check they are correct in the immediate window. if that doesnt identify the issue it might be worth sharing the rest of your code as i cant see an issue when i run it on its own